# Count number of values

Tags: jquery, html-select

I have several selector elements with class="select". There are duplicate option values in several of them. But I want to find the duplicate values that appear in EACH of the select and not only eg. 2 out of 5.

This is my edited code.

```
    var selector = $('.select')
    $('option', selector).each(function() {         
       if ($('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]', selector).length == 6) {
            $(this).clone().prop('selected', false).appendTo("#commonBranch_select");           
        }
    });
```

I trying to make a select contain one new option per dupliate in all other .select option.

6 of these but 'test' is present in all of them so I want that in #commonBranch_select

```
<select class="select">
<option value="test">
test
</option>
</select>
```

I removed the duplicates from the new list with

```
var map = {};
    $("#commonBranch_select option").each(function(){
        var value = $(this).text();
        if (map[value] == null){
            map[value] = true;
        } else {
            $(this).remove();
        }
    });
```

It works but but can probably be done better : )

Comment: Can a select box contain duplicate values? What is your code returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look for `option` elements with the same value like this:

```
var $selector = $('.select')
$('option', $selector).each(function() {    
    if ($('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]', $selector).length > 1) {
        // do something
    }
});
```

Alternatively, use `filter`:

```
var $duplicates = $('option', $selector).filter(function() {
    return $('option[value="' + $(this).val() + '"]', $selector).length > 1;
});
// now do something with $duplicates...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! My problem is that I only want it to return one time per instance of duplicate that exists in all select option and not every time. Hope you understand. The $duplicates solution makes my browser crash btw...